# How does multiplication in $\Omega X$ induce multiplication for chains of $\Omega X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, loop-spaces

I have a CW complex $K$ and a loop space $\Omega K$. By $Q(\Omega K)$ I denote the group generated by the singular cubes of $\Omega K$. Then the book says that "the  multiplication in $\Omega K$ induces ring structure in $Q(\Omega K)$ in the usual way". What is this usual way? All I can think of is that for $f,g:[0,1]^n\to \Omega K$ their product $h=fg$ works like that:
$$h(x_1,\dots,x_n)=f(x_1,\dots,x_n)g(x_1,\dots,x_n),$$ where product in $RHS$ is product of loops. Is this the correct interpretation? What else could it be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended multiplication induces the [Pontryagin product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_product) on homology $H_{\bullet}(\Omega K)$, so it takes something in degree $n$ and something in degree $m$ and produces something in degree $n+m$. Given a singular $n$-cube $f : [0, 1]^n \to \Omega K$ and a singular $m$-cube $g : [0, 1]^m \to \Omega K$, their product is

$$f \times g : [0, 1]^{n+m} \to \Omega K$$

given by the "external" product $f(x_1, \dots x_n) g(y_1, \dots y_m)$.